# Doctrine 2: Can entities be saved into sessions?

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm having a problem with lazy loading after I save an entity into a PHP session.  Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See [Serializing Entities](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/architecture.html#serializing-entities) in doctrine manual: (Everything you save in a session is serialized and deserialized.)

> Serializing entities can be problematic and is not really recommended, at least not as long as an entity instance still holds references to proxy objects or is still managed by an EntityManager.

There is a technical limitation that avoid private properties from being serialized when an entity is proxied (lazy-loaded entities are proxied).

This means that you have to avoid using `private` properties for the entities you want to serialize (use `protected` entities instead).

Also, if a lazy-loaded entity is not loaded at serialization time, it won't be loadable after de-serialization. So you have to make sure the entity is fully loaded before serializing it.

Comment: Thx Arnaud, that makes a lot of sense!  Is there a specific way to fully load an entity (for just this one instance)?

Comment: cloning it seems to be a good way to do it; this also removes references to entity persisters etc, which you must do too.

Comment: Arnaud, how does cloning solve this issue?  Wouldn't the cloned object still have a reference to a proxy?

Comment: proxies have a `__clone` method that ensures the entity is loaded, and removes references to the entity persister. `__clone` is called by PHP on the clone, just after cloning.

Comment: Arnaud, thx so much for your help!  One last question, what happens if you don't remove the entity persister?

Comment: it will be serialized too, and bad things will happen

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer quotes accurately the Doctrine documentation.

However, there are few more pages on the subject explaining how to serialize entities and store them the session.
[Entities in the Session](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/entities-in-session.html) says that the entities must be detached before storing in the session and then merged when restoring from the session.

[On this page](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html) there are sections about [detaching](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities) and [merging](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities) entities.

Saving:

```
$em = GetEntityManager();
$user = $em->find("User", 1);
$em->detach($user);
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;
```

Restoring:

```
$em = GetEntityManager();
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] instanceof User) {
    $user = $_SESSION['user'];
    $user = $em->merge($user);
}
```