# Why is my session data getting changed?

Tags: php, symfony, session, doctrine-orm

In symfony and Doctrine i am using the session to save a query result then later on i am filtering this result with some parameters.
The problem is that once the parameters are changed i can't get the original results set. Here is the code

## fetching results and saving to session

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$query->select("sp")
->from("CoreBundle:ServiceProvider","sp")
->innerJoin("sp.offers","offer")
->innerJoin("offer.service","service","with","offer.service = service")
->innerJoin("sp.firstImage","fi")
->andWhere("sp.city = :city_name")->setParameter("city_name",$cityName)
->orderBy("sp.points" ,"DESC")
->addOrderBy("sp.name" ,"ASC");
$queryAndFilters = $this->getFilters($query,$postData);
$query = $queryAndFilters['query'];
$filters=$queryAndFilters['filters'];
$paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
$pagination = $paginator->paginate(
    $query, /* query NOT result */
    $pageNumber,
    20/*limit per page*/
);

$query = $query->getQuery();
$query->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS, true);

$this->get('session')->set("results",$query->getResult());
```

and then in another function

## filtering the results

```
$results = $this->get('session')->get("results");

$filteredResults = array();

// print_r(array_keys($results[0]));
foreach($results as $result){
    $sp = $result;
    foreach($sp->getOffers() as $offer){
        // echo "found offer ".$offer->getName()." with price ".$offer->getPrice()."<br />";
        $sp->removeOffer($offer);
        if($offer->getPrice() < $minPrice || $offer->getPrice() > $maxPrice){

        }else{
            $sp->addOffer($offer);
            // echo 'added $offer '.$offer->getName()." with price : ".$offer->getPrice()."<br />";
        }
        if(sizeof($sp->getOffers()) > 0 ){
            array_push($filteredResults,$sp);
        }
    }
}
```

the first time i change the $minPrice and $maxPrice variables the results are filtered right and exactly what i need
but after raising the $maxPrice again the high prices are not being added to the $filteredResults

i tried also to assign $offer and $result to new variables but still not working
any idea how to fix this ?

ps. i can't change the query or to fetch them already with the query.

Comment: Are you _rewrite_ the entities in the session after change their attributes?

Comment: No rewriting is happening this is the whole code related to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save entities in the session this entities are [serialized](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/architecture.html#serializing-entities)  with the values that actual at the serialization moment. Next changes of entities are not affect the stored values if you don't rewrite them in the session.

Also entitiy serializing has [some limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7473189/1220930) on `private` properties.

Comment: i dont really understand why serializing would change the results if i DID NOT change them

Comment: as you see in the code the serialized is the getArrayResult() so i serialzed an array not even entities and even though what ever i serialized i did not change them i just added a new array removing from this array is working but readding is not and this is the question

Comment: Try to `unserialize(serialize($query->getResult()))`.

Comment: executing this getting me 0 offers in $sp->getOffers();

Comment: It means that offers just do not serialized. Is relevant property `protected` or `private`?

Comment: its 'private'  /**
     * @var ServiceOffer
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ServiceOffer", mappedBy="serviceProvider")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"points"="DESC"})
     */
    private $offers;

Comment: > If you intend to serialize (and unserialize) entity instances that still hold references to proxy objects you may run into problems with private properties because of technical limitations.

Comment: hmmmm it seems that i need to find another way around, thanks 
i will mark it as true just for reference